# Can't find App.config file for Windows Console app

Tags: c#, app-config, windows-console

I have a Windows console app that has an App.config file.  The console app is to be executed from a SQL Agent job.  In app.config I store a database connection.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Northwind" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sqlUser;Password=secret" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I get the connection string at runtime like so:

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
```

My code works fine in debug and can read the connection string from App.config.

When I build for release, there is no app.config in the release folder.  When I copy the .exe over to the server, I get "Object reference not set..." when trying 
to get the connection string. Tried manually copying app.config, but no joy.

Found this, but it doesn't match since my build doesn't create a file named MyApp.exe.config.
Edit:  It doesn't create any file ending in *.exe.config.

[Loading app.config file in Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192383/loading-app-config-file-in-release)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  Does the App.config become a part of the .EXE in a Windows console app?

Comment: Can you try change `App.config` file properties (CopyToOutputDirectory = Always)? May be it helps

Comment: app.config only exists in your project. When you say"MyApp.exe.config" do you literally mean that because you must replace "MyApp" with your actual app name.

Comment: @Crowcoder: fair question, I didn't mean "MyApp" specifically. It doesn't create any file ending in *.exe.config.

Comment: Right Click your project --> Add --> New Item --> Application Configuration File. paste your connection string xml tags. run your app in release see if it generates it now.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have file extensions for known file types hidden and you just don't see it in the bin folder?

Comment: @AdemCatamak I've tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: @Crowcoder No, I don't have hide file extensions checked.  And I can see the original App.config file (and AdemCatamak's App1.config) in the release folder since I copied it there.

Comment: Well the App.config doesn't do any good to an executing application. I've never had nor heard of a problem like this. If you create another console app do you get the config file in the bin folder?